# disassembly Linux kernel using objdump

Tags: linux, objdump

If I try to disassem Linux kernel, it takes quite long time due to the big size of Linux elf-binary.

Is there a way to only disassem a function or a symbol, for instance start_kernel function?

What I don't want is to use grep, since it anyway takes very long time.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have compiled kernel with debugging symbols included, there are no symbols for objdump to use. It is highly unlikely the kernel binary has debugging symbols included, unless you've specifically compiled it with such options.

In case your kernel binary does have debugging symbols, they can be found using `nm -g` and then further used with `objdump -j <symbol>`.

Comment: -j option is for section. And, not work for function.

Answer (score 0):

You can not disassemble particular function or symbol alone but instead of full kernel image, you can disassemble specific object file.

ex.

```
objdump -DS XYZ.o > XYZ.S
```